# Changing a global list inside a function

Tags: python

Trying to get the deck list to shuffle in the function shuffle_deck but when I edit it in create_deck it's not saving the changes. I thought appending it inside the function changes the list in the global field not just inside the function but could be wrong. How do I get the shuffle_deck function to see the appended deck from create_deck rather than an empty one?

```
import random
deck=[]

def Create_Deck():
    suits = ('Spades','Hearts','Clubs','Diamonds')
    for suit in suits:
        for card in range(1,14):
            if card == 1:
                card = 'Ace'
            elif card == 11:
                card = 'Jack'
            elif card == 12:
                card = 'Queen'
            elif card == 13:
                card = 'King'
            deck.append(str(card) + ' of ' + suit)
    print(deck)


def shuffle_deck():
    random.shuffle(deck)
    print(deck)`



print(shuffle_deck())
print(Create_Deck())
```

I want to be able to print(deck) in the shuffle_deck and it be a randomized version of the deck in create_deck.

Comment: Why are you shuffling an empty deck and *then* putting cards in?

Comment: In other words: you must first create the deck before shuffling it. Swap the last two lines of your code.

Comment: thanks guys, you guys are exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you are calling the functions is wrong. The value of `deck` is an empty list `[]` when `shuffle_deck` is being called. Simply call `Create_deck` before `shuffle_deck`.

```
print(Create_Deck())
print(shuffle_deck())
```

**Some extra information on how and where to use `global`:**
If the global variable points to a **mutable python object**, like a `list`, there is no need for the use of `global` declaration. However, you can not use an assignment statement with the variable. Mutating the object without changing the reference of the variable will work without  using `global` declaration.

For variables referring to immutable data, an assignment statement essentially changes the reference of the variable, which when happens, python creates a local copy of the variable and does not touch the global data. To directly modify the global variable, declare it as `global` at the beginning of the function.

```
x = 10

def change_x():
    x = 20  # this is a local `x`
    print(f'After changing: x = {x}')

print(f'Before function call: x = {x}')
change_x()
print(f'After function call: x = {x}')
```

Output:

```
Before function call: x = 10
After changing: x = 20
After function call: x = 10
```

Now, lets use the `global` declaration

```
x = 10

def change_x():
    global x
    x = 20
    print(f'After changing: x = {x}')

print(f'Before function call: x = {x}')
change_x()
print(f'After function call: x = {x}')
```

Output:

```
Before function call: x = 10
After changing: x = 20
After function call: x = 20
```

---

For mutable types, `global` declaration is not required.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]

def change_x():
    x.append(4)
    print(f'After changing: x = {x}')

print(f'Before function call: x = {x}')
change_x()
print(f'After function call: x = {x}')
```

Output:

```
Before function call: x = [1, 2, 3]
After changing: x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
After function call: x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, assigning a different value to it will not work.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]

def change_x():
    x = [10, 20, 30]
    print(f'After changing: x = {x}')

print(f'Before function call: x = {x}')
change_x()
print(f'After function call: x = {x}')
```

Output:

```
Before function call: x = [1, 2, 3]
After changing: x = [10, 20, 30]
After function call: x = [1, 2, 3]
```